# Get the property of the difference between two objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, difference

Let's say that I have an object which looks like this:

```
{
  prop1: false,
  prop2: false,
  prop3: false
}
```

and another object which looks like this:

```
{
  prop1: false,
  prop2: true,
  prop3: false
}
```

where the difference is within the `prop2` property. Is there any way or library (vanilla preferred though) which will compare the two objects, find the property with the different value, and return the property name (in this case `prop2`)?

I have tried using the difference and differenceBy functions in lodash to no success. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could filter the keys (assuming same keys) by checking the unequal value.

```js
var obj1 = { prop1: false, prop2: false, prop3: false },
    obj2 = { prop1: false, prop2: true, prop3: false },
    difference = Object.keys(obj1).filter(k => obj1[k] !== obj2[k]);
    
console.log(difference);
```

Comment: This solution does not take in account that the input could be a nested object. A better solution could be the one here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30476150/javascript-deep-comparison-recursively-objects-and-properties, adding the keys differences as result.

Comment: @loretoparisi, this solution takes exactly the object of the op, not a not given nested object.

Comment: you are right, I mean to be as generic as possible.

Comment: @NinaScholz so I have asked new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591096/compare-nested-objects-in-javascript-and-return-keys-equality

Comment: [Not work for KeyboardEvent object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235864/object-keyskeyboardevent-only-get-one-istrusted-key-rather-than-all-keys)

Answer (score 3):

This function will extract all the difference between two objects. It will also works on nested objects. This code uses some [lodash](https://lodash.com/) functions. (function names that starts with "_.")

```
function difference(object, base) {
    function changes(object, base) {
        return _.transform(object, function(result, value, key) {
            if (!_.isEqual(value, base[key])) {
                result[key] = (_.isObject(value) && _.isObject(base[key])) ? changes(value, base[key]) : value;
            }
        });
    }
    return changes(object, base);
}
```

Answer (score -9):

this is the fastest and simplest method

```
var a ={
  prop1: false,
  prop2: false,
  prop3: false
}

var b={
  prop1: false,
  prop2: true,
  prop3: false
}

 JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)
```

this return false.
order of props is also important

Comment: This does not answer the question