# Compare nested objects with arrays in JavaScript and return keys equality

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, compare

I have two nested objects obj1 and obj2 and I want to compare them and the recursively return an object that for each nested key has a equality-like boolean flag

So for a given `obj1` like

```js
var obj1 = {
    prop1: "BAR",
    prop2: "foo",
    prop3: [
        {
            id: 1,
            prop4: "foo",
            prop5: "a"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            prop4: "foo",
            prop5: "b"
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            prop4: "foo",
            prop5: "e"
        }
    ]
}
```

And the `obj2` like

```js
var obj2 = {
    prop1: "FOO",
    prop2: "foo",
    prop3: [
        {
            id: 1,
            prop4: "bar",
            prop5: "b"
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            prop4: "foo",
            prop5: "a"
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            prop4: "foo",
            prop5: "e"
        }
    ],
    prop6: "new"
}
```

It should return

```js
var equality = {
    prop1: false,
    prop2: true,
    prop3: [
        {
            id: 1,
            prop4: false,
            prop5: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            prop4: true,
            prop5: false
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            prop4: null,
            prop5: null
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            prop4: true,
            prop5: true
        }
    ],
    prop6: true
}
```

I have to compare two objects and return true for same values. And for inside the array I have to compare with ID(key) and check if prop4, prop 5 have changed and return false if changed.
For Data in obj 1 and not present in obj 2 => we can neglector show as null as shown in result(equality)
For Data in obj 2 and not present in obj 1 => should be flagged as true for all props in it.

The solution given by Nina Scholz in [Compare nested objects in JavaScript and return keys equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591096/compare-nested-objects-in-javascript-and-return-keys-equality) has helped me but only problem I am facing is for prop3 I am getting as nested fields but I need it as same formatting as the array.

It would be very much helpful for me if any one get the right solution. I am new to JavaScript and learning it would help me a lot.

Comment: why `equality.prop1` is `true`? because `obj1.prop1` isn't equal to `obj2.prop1`, shouldn't it be `false` ?

Comment: Yes it should be false. I will edit the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: And why you keep `number` ?

Comment: I want them to be compared with number not by index so I needed it. So as shown in my result the number will be present. I think this works and if you could do this scenario and  " For Data in obj 1 and not present in obj 2 => we can neglect For Data in obj 2 and not present in obj 1 => should be flagged as true for all props in it."  this that wouold be very helpful for me. Thank you very much again.

Comment: It helped me, need to check for number and other condition as I said  I need to compare them with number and see if in that array for  that particular "number", the props have changed are not.

Comment: add this line `if (key == "number" && key in x && key in y && x[key] == y[key]) { temp[key] = x[key]; continue; }` in 3rd `if..for..of` loop, To Keep `number`

Comment: Thank you very much it helped me. Just need to convert to es6 and good to go. I appreciate that.

Comment: I checked it and it is working fine. Only one problem is if there is difference in length of the arrays I am getting it result as number = false for some indexes. Just looking into it

Comment: So when you want to keep `number` exactly  ?

Comment: Okay I got it. So I am checking always with number and " 
if Data in obj 1 is  not present in obj 2 => we can neglect
example  obj1 - prop3[2]- number 3 ; 
if Data is present obj 2 and not present in obj 1 => should be flagged as true for all props in it. obj2 - prop3[2]-number 4. I edited the question and sorry for the confusion. I am new to this and learning it.

Comment: Number should always be present as equality = {
     prop1: false,
     prop2: true,
      prop3: [
              {
                number: 1,
                prop4: false,
                prop5: false 
              },
              {
                number: 2,
                prop4: true,
                prop5: false
              },
              
      {
            number: 4,
            prop4: true,
            prop5: true 
          }
            ],
     prop6: true
   }

Comment: Ok! We are checking  , If  `key` is `'number'`, And both object should have it , And `number` in both  object  should equal... Got it ?

Comment: Instead of comparing with array index, the comparision point here would be the number, I have to compare with number in both arrays and return true or false for the props inside that that paricular index of number? Is it clear now, or did I confuse you more. To be clear, I have to compare number 1 items with number 1 items in obj 1 and 2 and  see if prop 4 and prop5 are same or different. For special case like number 3 (deleted in obj 2) in obj 1 i can neglect it as it is not present in obj 2, but for number 4 (added in obj 2)  in obj 2 which is not present in obj 1, I have to show as true

Comment: All time, I have hard time understanding every questions on stack overflow. Unless There is an example . So can I have an example?

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. I understand your concern. I have updated the question codes please check obj1 obj 2 and equality, We are almost there and might need some tweaking. Just need to compare prop3 in each obj with id's always. please see the edited question now. If a particular list item is not available in the second array, it should return null. I am able to make it clear now?

Comment: Please let me if I had been able to make it clear or  is it confusing and need to explain it better from myside.

Comment: Trying to do better explanation, just need to compare two arrays with ID number(id=1 in obj1 compare to id=1 in obj2) in each array and display true/false for (prop4, prop5) equal/unequal values. If a item(id =3 in obj 1) in list is present in obj1 and not present in obj 2 we can ignore it and don't display anything in result or we can display that in result as {id: 3, prop4: null, prop5: null} and if an ID list item is present in obj 2  (ID 4) and not in obj 1 just display in result as true for its siblings {id:4, prop4: true, prop5: true}.

Comment: Refactored code a bit. And [your solution](https://gist.github.com/nurmohammed840/667c0839e4adbd476457da6327dfce2b)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tricky recursion can do the job.

```js
var obj1 = { prop1: 1, prop2: "foo", prop3: [{ number: 1, prop4: "foo", prop5: "a" }, { number: 2, prop4: "foo", prop5: "b" }] }
var obj2 = { prop1: 3, prop2: "foo", prop3: [{ number: 1, prop4: "bar", prop5: "b" }, { number: 2, prop4: "foo", prop5: "a" }, { number: 3, prop4: "foo", prop5: "e" }], prop6: "new" }

const isObject = v => v !== null && typeof v == "object";

function getDifference(x, y = x) {
    if (x === undefined) x = y;
    if (Array.isArray(x) && Array.isArray(y)) {
        const temp = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < (x.length + y.length) / 2; i++)
            temp.push(getDifference(x[i], y[i]))

        return temp;
    }
    if (isObject(x) && isObject(y)) {
        const temp = {};
        for (const key of new Set([...Object.keys(x), ...Object.keys(y)]))
            temp[key] = getDifference(x[key], y[key])

        return temp;
    }
    return x === y;
}

console.log(getDifference(obj1, obj2));
```