# How to compare two objects in javascript and get difference?

Tags: javascript, compareobject

I have two objects to compare. I want to find the key and its value which is different in the second object. Which should return only the different key and its value in an object.

```
const obj1={name:"abc",age:21,place:"xyz"}
const obj2={name:"pqr",age:21}
```

So, here I want to return `{name:"pqr"}` as here the name value is different from the first object.
And I have tried ,

```
const returnObject = Object.assign({}, findOwner, data);
```

and

```
const returnObject = { ...findOwner, ...data };
```

but these are returning not exactly what I want.

Comment: What have tried? Add any attempts you've made to solve this issue.

Comment: Here's the first result of a google search for your question title: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572826/generic-deep-diff-between-two-objects

Comment: Please add your inputs, expected output and the code you've tried. There are plenty of similar questions incuding nested objects: [Compare nested objects in JavaScript and return keys equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55591096) and [Get the property of the difference between two objects in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930387)

Comment: Please read [tour] _"Don't ask about...

    Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)"_

Comment: You can see the changes in the question

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solutions is,

```
function Newdifference(origObj, newObj) {
  function changes(newObj, origObj) {
    let arrayIndexCounter = 0
    return transform(newObj, function (result, value, key) {
      if (value && !isObject(value) && !isEqual(JSON.stringify(value), JSON.stringify(origObj[key]))) {
        let resultKey = isArray(origObj) ? arrayIndexCounter++ : key
        result[resultKey] = (isObject(value) && isObject(origObj[key])) ? changes(value, origObj[key]) : value
      }
    });
  };
  return changes(newObj, origObj);
}
```

This function will return the changes which are traced in two objects

Comment: Error `Uncaught ReferenceError: transform is not defined`. This means transform is an helper method which is not included in this solution

Answer (score 0):

I found better way to compare any count of type with any property order:

```
let isEqual = (...params) => params.map(Object.keys).reduce((prev, cur) => [...prev, ...cur], []).every(key => params.every(param => param[key] === params[0][key]))
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCJP1.png)